# Creating dynamic overlay grid in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, vector-grid

I have a shapefile of multiple polygon features corresponding to geographic regions that vary in area. The task is to create a dynamic grid over each polygon, with the size of the squares for each grid dependent on the area of the underlying polygon, e.g. if area of polygon exceeds a certain threshold then grid square width and height is x metres by x metres. I can use the Grid Index Features tool in ArcMap (v 10.7) to create one grid over a single polygon, so am wondering if this can be extended to loop through multiple polygons, producing the required grid for each polygon. The ultimate aim is to create input for the Data Driven Pages tool (or the equivalent Map Series tool in ArcGIS Pro) to produce a map atlas for each geographic region, including an overview map plus maps for each of the individual grid squares to provide greater detail.

Comment: To do this I *think* you will be best to use ArcPy and Create Fishnet but it sounds like you may have several unmarked questions here.  As per our [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Use model builder and iterate over each polygon calling the Grid Index Feature tool. 2 minute job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made some progress using the model builder in ArcGIS Pro to iterate over each polygon calling the Grid Index Feature (GIF) tool. Is it possible to add an 'if' statement after the iteration step to apply a different sized grid using the GIF tool, e.g. if polygon area is less than x then create grid squares of 500m x 500m, else create grid squares of 1km x 1km?